# Como criar critério DetachedCriteria para um campo de uma tabela de Join?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Primeira vez que mexo com isso e estou com dificuldade de montar a query adequadamente.

Eis o meu código feito da maneira errada, logo não está obedecendo as condições:

```
public IList<Ficha> ObterFichas()
{        
    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Ficha>();
    criteria.SetMaxResults(1);

    DetachedCriteria criteriaExportacao = DetachedCriteria.For<Exportacao>();       
    criteriaExportacao.CreateAlias("exportacao","e", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin).Add(Restrictions.Eq("exportacao.Exportado", null)).Add(Property.ForName("e.Exportado").In(criteria));

    var ok = DomainService.FichaRepository().LoadAll(criteria);

    return ok;
}
```

É retornado o primeiro registro de ficha, mas o primeiro registro não possui o campo **Exportado** como nulo.

Tenho a tabela **ficha** e a tabela **exportacao** no meu banco. É um relacionamento mapeado de 1 para 1. Na tabela **ficha** e na tabela **exportacao** eu tenho IdFicha como PK e PK/FK respectivamente.

Dadas essas informações o que eu desejo fazer é montar uma query que traga apenas 1 linha de resultado com o left join entre tabela **ficha** e tabela **exportacao**. Que deve trazer apenas os resultados nulos conforme tentei fazer na condição do meu código, mas que está errado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui, ficou dessa forma:

```
public IList<Ficha> ObterFichas()
{        
    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Ficha>();
    criteria.SetMaxResults(1);

    criteria.CreateAlias("exportacao", "e",NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin).Add(Restrictions.IsNull("e.Exportado"));

    var ok = DomainService.FichaRepository().LoadAll(criteria);

    return ok;
}
```